# JavaFX: CSS variables

Tags: css, javafx

I have four buttons that I want to style the same way except that each one of them has a unique image. there are three styles one for normal state and the others are for hover and focused states. Doing this in `CSS` which is the recommended way would take a lot of repetition, and I searched in the net and it seems variables are not supported in `CSS`. So is there a way around this, or would it be more pragmatic to do this in code.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: If those 3 states that you mention for all 4 buttons are the same, you can use 3 simple selectors to specify that under a generic `btn` class. If you can share some code I could help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS correctly will avoid repetition. You can share code between four buttons in one of a few ways.

**Have the buttons share a class and style their differences:**

```
<div id="btn1" class="button">Button 1</div>
<div id="btn2" class="button">Button 2</div>
<div id="btn3" class="button">Button 3</div>
<div id="btn4" class="button">Button 4</div>

<style>
    .button {
      color: blue;
      background: white;
      /* etc... */
    }

    #btn1 { background-image: url('uniqueimage1.png');
    #btn2 { background-image: url('uniqueimage2.png');
    /* etc... */
</style>
```

---

Or, less preferably...

**Target multiple elements in one CSS rule:**

```
<div id="btn1">Button 1</div>
<div id="btn2">Button 2</div>
<div id="btn3">Button 3</div>
<div id="btn4">Button 4</div>

<style>
    #btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4 {
      color: blue;
      background: white;
      /* etc... */
    }

    #btn1 { background-image: url('uniqueimage1.png');
    #btn2 { background-image: url('uniqueimage2.png');
    /* etc... */
</style>
```

Comment: It's a question about javafx, not about html!

Comment: Yes it is a question about javafx, but the answer works! even though if there is a better answer for javafx, it would be better